# Add Tag Function for a Form

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a `Task` form for my `Taskmanager`. I'm building to get more experience with symfony.

However I use the collection field to add some `Tags` to a `Task`.

When I create a task, I don't want to add only a new `Task`, so I used the entity field to choose an action from my `Tag` table in the database.

But this is not exactly where I am looking for. Is there a Tutorial or Example to type in a `Tag` and select it like on the bottom of the stackoverflow.com Ask Question page?

I don't know how to realize this.

Comment: Can you reformulate the question? What is `Tag`? How are those entities related between each other? Is it your requirement to create an input field with space-separated tag names?

Comment: Tags should be some description words for my Task. For Example Task(Learn) Tags(Language, Java, PHP) . Its a biderectional ManyToMany relationship. And its not really a requirement, but its something i wan't to learn and implement.

Comment: You are saying that it's not exactly what you are looking for but you are not exactly saying what you are looking for...

Comment: It sounds like a javascript solution would be better; take a look at select2: http://ivaynberg.github.com/select2/

Comment: thanks a lot Lightart. I used the GenemuFormBundle with the select2 plugin. Just what i needed.